# How to check foreground/background status in Windows 10 UWP javascript

Tags: javascript, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am developing a Windows 10 UWP App in javascript.
One of the requirement is to show a notification but only when the app is in background, not foreground.

My question is, what is the best way to check if the app is running in background/foreground, using javascript. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the same APIs you use from a Web page: Use [`document.hasFocus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hasFocus) to determine whether the app has focus. You will also receive the [`window.blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) and [`window.focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus) events when you lose and regain focus.

Comment: I knew this. But even if we have this checking, Windows App will not run that code when it's in the background because nothing will run when it's in the background except background task.

Comment: But thanks for the reply, I am marking this as the best answer.

Comment: The app can run in the background if you have requested extended execution.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the best way to check if the app is running in background/foreground, using javascript.

If you check the [app lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle#running-in-the-background), you could use [WebUIApplication.EnteredBackground Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.webui.webuiapplication.enteredbackground) and [WebUIApplication.LeavingBackground Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.webui.webuiapplication.leavingbackground) to do judgement. For example, you could use [ApplicationData.LocalSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData#properties-) to store the states of current app. When the `EnteredBackground` or `LeavingBackground` event is fired, you could change this localsettings value in its event handler. Then, when you want to detect the app's states, you could get this localsettings value and do judgement.